# PHP SoapClient arguments only work when i use StdClass

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

i'm trying to consume a SOAP API [DOC](http://jsserver20.jimpisoft.pt/Rentway_WS_Demo/getCountries.asmx?op=getCountries) [WSDL](http://jsserver20.jimpisoft.pt/Rentway_WS_Demo/getCountries.asmx?wsdl) and for some reason the requests always fail unless i use stdClass instances as arguments, and i'm trying to find a way around this cause i just don't like doing it this way and would much prefer to use associative arrays instead.

```
/* I'd like to get rid of these two classes if possible */
class countriesRequest{
    public $companyCode = "9999";
    public $allCountries = true;
}

class getCountries{
    public $objRequest;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->objRequest = new countriesRequest;
    }
}


class Countries extends ApiMethod
{
    /**
     * @var string API Endpoint
     */
    private $endpoint;

    public function getAllCountries() {

        $client = new SoapClient("http://jsserver20.jimpisoft.pt/Rentway_WS_Demo/getCountries.asmx?wsdl", ['trace' => 1]);
        try {
            $result = $client->getCountries(new getCountries());
            var_dump($result->getCountriesResult->countries->any);
        } catch(SoapFault $exception) {
            dd($client->__getLastRequest());
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever i try to use associative arrays, the SOAP Server returns an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." so for those of you more experienced with SOAP, does this service in this case *require* me to use stdClasses as arguments? Or is there any way i can use assoc arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the associative array and later transform it to a stdClass

with:

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($yourAssociativeArray));
```

or if isn't a nested array (just key value) you can do:

```
$object = (object)$yourAssociativeArray;
```

Comment: After some trial and error that worked, the answer was that simple all along haha thanks :)

Comment: This is just a workaround. It's better to understand the error message and write your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the parameter must be able to be used as a reference. To do that you have to assign it to a variable first.

```
$getCountriesRequest = new getCountries();
$getCountriesResponse = $client->getCountries($request);
```

You can read about passing by reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: The problem here is that the data i send in those objects is inherited by my main class and i don't want to have to mess around with passing variables down a whole daisy-chain of classes in order to make a simple SOAP call work.

That's why i accepted the workaround it's pretty clever and does exactly what i asked, cleanly turn an array of data from my main class into objects i can use for these SOAP requests.